# Get combobox selected from another form dynamically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox, vb.net-2010

I have a combobox in a form1 and a datagridview in another form2.
I want to get the combobox selected with a value from the datagridview in the second form
I use the code below in form2 and it works:

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

            form1.CBO_fournisseur.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

But what I want to do is that the name of the form is passed dynamically to avoid using and IFELSE clause to enumerate all the forms I have in my project that use form2

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

        If formbon2.Name = "FRM_BN_RECEPTION_CUIR" Then
            FRM_BN_RECEPTION_CUIR.CBO_fournisseur.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        ElseIf formbon2.Name = "frm_reception_acc_provisoire" Then
            frm_reception_acc_provisoire.CBO_1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString

        End If



        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

[image: Screen shot of the 2 forms]

Comment: I am having a hard time to understand what you are asking for. Can you possibly simplify it or use other words? Also I cannot seem to find any question in this text :/

Comment: Sorry @WozzeC :)I Edited my question.Hope I'm more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got what you want to do. I strongly suggest you stop using the Form as a Shared resource.

Use a constructor like this in your Form2:

```
Private ParentFormCombo as Combobox
Public Sub New(ByVal pCmb as Combobox)
  ParentFormCombo = pCmb
End Sub
```

Then in your doubleclick you just change the text of ParentFormCombo

```
ParentFormCombo.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Then you have to stop using:

```
FrmList_View.Show()
```

Now you should always use the constructor instead (New()). So do the following instead:

```
Dim f As New FrmList_View(CBO_fournisseur)
'or
Dim f As New FrmList_View(CBO_1)
f.Show()
```